# Combining Response of 2 API call by RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I have 2 request with different response that I want to merge response of them together by using RxJava .
The request one has response like this :

```
{
"A":{
"id" : ""
},
"B":{}
}
```

And the request two has response like this :

```
{
"A": {
"name" : ""
},
"C" :{}
}
```

As the final result I want to combine 2 response blocks of API calls with a pattern which includes all fields of 2 response like this :

```
{
"A" {
"id" : "",
"name" : ""
},

"B" :{},
"C" : {},
}
```

I use retrofit for my Api calls and Also I know a little about zip and combineLatest operations in RxJava. But I don't know the best way for combining.

Comment: Does B and C have similar values in it or they have different data?

Comment: @arungiri_10 They are different and I need both of them in my result. Also I need to combined value of A in my result.

Comment: This doesn't concern RxJava. Write your `zip()` function taking two responses and return one response.

Comment: Do you use retrofit to make api calls? I have a solution and will post in sometime. However, it would be using retrofit for api calls.

Comment: @arungiri_10 yes I forgot to say I use retrofit, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to create POJO classes. Let's say DataMain, DataA, DataB, DataC

DataA class (contains id and name):

```
public class DataA {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public DataA setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now DataB class:

```
public class DataB {
    @SerializedName("bid")
    private String bid;
}
```

Now DataC class:

```
public class DataC {
    @SerializedName("cid")
    private String cid;

    public String getCid() {
        return cid;
    }
}
```

Now comes the DataMain class (contains DataA, dataB, DataC)

```
public class DataMain {
    @SerializedName("A")
    public DataA dataA;

    @SerializedName("B")
    public DataB dataB;

    @SerializedName("C")
    public DataC dataC;

    public DataA getDataA() {
        return dataA;
    }

    public DataMain setDataA(DataA dataA) {
        this.dataA = dataA;
        return this;
    }

    public DataC getDataC() {
        return dataC;
    }

    public DataMain setDataC(DataC dataC) {
        this.dataC = dataC;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Based on the JSON structure we have created the POJO classes. Now we will be doing 2 API calls something similar to below

```
//getApi() - initialization of retrofit
public static DataMainApi getApi() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("your URL")
        .build()
        .create(DataMainApi.class);
}

//Here we will get DataA with id and DataB
public static Observable<DataMain> getData1() {
    return getApi().getDataMain1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}

//Here we will get DataA with name and DataC
public static Observable<DataMain> getData2() {
    return getApi().getDataMain2().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Now we will call the above 2 APIs using Rx-Java

```
    Observable
        .zip(
            getData1(),
            getData2(),
            (dataMain1, dataMain2) -> dataMain1.setDataA(
                dataMain1.getDataA().setName(dataMain2.getDataA().getName())
            ).setDataC(dataMain2.getDataC())
        )
        .subscribe(
            result -> //Result with combined data,
            error -> error.printStackTrace()
        );
```

Basically what we are doing is get Data1 (with DataA(id) and DataB) and get Data2(with DataA(name) and DataC), and copying the values to DataMain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but don't use Rx like that. The question was about the difference between zip and combine operator.

Comment: @Scrobot I totally agree. I got into the flow and forgot the usage of zip operator. Updating my answer with zip operator usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxJava's [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator to combine result of two api calls. You will also need to create a DTO object to represent the combination of both the API calls

Answer (score 0):

CombineLatest work in concurrency mode. If we watch to picture below

[image: description]

you can see that you have 2 flows and data combines in next case:

`1` combines with `A` ->  result `1A`. When the next input value at first thread is `2`. Combiner watches at the second thread and sees value `A`. Combine operation returns value `2A`. And so on.

Let's imagine, that we have next case:

```java
        Observable<Integer> producer1 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5)
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                    System.out.println("complete");
                });

        Observable<String> producer2 = Observable.just("A", "B", "C", "D", "F");

        System.out.println("combineLatest");
        Observable.combineLatest(producer1, producer2, (i, s) -> i + s)
                .subscribe((result) -> {
                    System.out.println(result);
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

This code will output the next thing

```
combineLatest
complete
5A
5B
5C
5D
5F
```

Because value `5` is the latest value in the thread. And then it makes last modifications - it's complete(because of `just` operator).

So, let's resume the first part: **if you have the case, when you need to have some concurrency state - you can use `combineLatest`.**

Zip - is merging values in the sequence in which they entered.

[image]

And if we watch the same case, but with `zip`

```java
Observable<Integer> producer1 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5)
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                    System.out.println("complete");
                });

        Observable<String> producer2 = Observable.just("A", "B", "C", "D", "F");

        System.out.println("\nzip");
        Observable.zip(producer1, producer2, (i, s) -> i + s)
                .subscribe((result) -> {
                    System.out.println(result);
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

The output will be

```
zip
complete
1A
2B
3C
4D
5F
```

So, in your case, if you need to merge two models, I recommend you to choose `zip` operator.